# Save the return of a callback nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on the router-os library of mikrotik routers.
I'm having trouble displaying a call to the API outside the callback. The foo variable should contain the object recover in the API only I can not get around the asynchronization problem

```
var MikroNode = require('mikronode-ng2');

const USER = "sofian";
const PASSWD = "sofian"

var toto;

var connection = MikroNode.getConnection('10.0.0.1', USER, PASSWD)

connection.connect(function (conn) {
    var chan = conn.openChannel();
    conn.closeOnDone = true;
    chan.write('/ip/address/print', function () {
        chan.closeOnDone = true;
        chan.on('done', function (data) {
            var parsed = MikroNode.parseItems(data);
            toto = parsed
            parsed.forEach(function (item) {
                console.log('Interface/IP: ' + item.interface + "/" + item.address);
            })
        })
    })
})

console.log(toto);
```

return to terminal :

```
undefined
Interface/IP: Lan/10.0.0.1/8
Interface/IP: Wan Orange/192.168.1.254/24
```

Thanks

EDIT with Promise :

I try it but it still does not work

```
var MikroNode = require('mikronode-ng2');

const USER = "sofian";
const PASSWD = "sofian"

var connection = MikroNode.getConnection('10.0.0.1', USER, PASSWD)
var result;

function test() {
    connection.getConnectPromise().then( function (conn) {
        conn.getCommandPromise('/ip/address/print').then(async function resolved(values) {
            // console.log('Addreses: ' + JSON.stringify(values));
            result = 'Addreses: ' + JSON.stringify(values)
            return await result;
        })
    })
}

console.log(test())
```

terminal :

```
undefined
```

I add async / await but it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** pull asynchronous data (such as `data`, `parsed`, etc) into a synchronous context. Think about it: By passing a callback to `connection.connect()` you're telling it "call this function at some indeterminate time in the future, when you're done connecting" and then the code continues immediately and hits `console.log(toto)` relatively way before the callback has executed. There is no way for data created in that callback to travel back in time.

If you want to write asynchronous code as though it were synchronous, use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) - the library you're using [does seem to support promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mikronode-ng2?activeTab=readme), so you'd have to use those functions instead to do it that way.

Comment: I edit my post.

Comment: The function `test()` does not return a value. Additionally, you're still trying to pull asynchronous values out into a synchronous context. The best you're going to do is have access to it in a callback or async function

Comment: Can you illustrate your message with code, I do not understand how to solve my problem.

Comment: I still try to solve this problem but I do not understand. I put a little await / async everywhere but it does not work.

Comment: Please view the answers for the two questions yours has been marked a duplicate of.

Comment: Could you help me please